# Why does setting the class variable NSArray require me to use the accessor method?

Tags: ios, nsfetchrequest

I'm using a NSFetchRequest to create a section in a UITableView based on objects stored in Core Data.

In the viewDidLoad I do the fetch request and set the returned array of NSManagedObjects to a class variable NSArray *allEvents. I was setting the array returned from the fetch request like so:

```
    allEvents = [context executeFetchRequest:eventFetchRequest error:&error];
```

I was getting a EXEC_BAD_ACCESS error when I tried calling [allEvents count] in my numberOfRowsInSection later on.

I managed to fix the problem by setting the array from the fetch request by adding self to the above line of code:

```
    self.allEvents = [context executeFetchRequest:eventFetchRequest error:&error];
```

Can anyone explain why this worked? I've run into similar situations and would love to know what's going on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the "allEvents" property on your object is a retain property, so in the first scenario the array is not being retained, and has been deallocated by the time you access it.

Comment: It's is a retain property. So does that mean when I call the accessor method it's retain count goes up?

Comment: A better way to think of it is that retain properties "own" the current object that was set with them, and relinquish ownership when a new object is set. The mechanism for this is that they increase and decrease the retain count though, yes. The synthesized method looks something like: - (void) setFoo:(id)newFoo { if (foo != newFoo) { [foo release]; foo = [newFoo retain]; } }